# Finding out if a TextBox is valid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When I bind a Textboxes Text-Property via databinding to a double value it's Default-behaviour is very Handy: It automatically validates the Content of my TextBox and if it's not valid for a double it marks it with a red border. My Problem now is: How do I find out if the Content of that TextBox is valid or not in the code behind?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you taking about the code-behind the xaml or for the viewmodel?

Comment: Implement IDataErrorInfo in your object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Validation.GetErrors method to get the value of the System.Windows.Controls.Validation.Errors attached property.

See sample code below:

```
var result = Validation.GetErrors([TextBoxInstance]);
if (result.Count > 0) // has errors.
{
    //write your logic here.
}
```